# Download and saving file using Asynctask is not working properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I have used the following class for downloading a file and saving it to the sdcard.

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
                int count;

            try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"PurchasedFrames/"+filename);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;

            }
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                 Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
                 mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
                File file = new File("/sdcard/PurchasedFrames/", filename );
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                     ImageView frame = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
                     frame.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            }
        }
```

**Dialog method**

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My problem using the above codes, progressBar will appear but it will disappear without finishing and no download occur. I could't notice any **logcat** error or any other error from debugging. Can anybody tell what can be happen or how to overcome from this problem?

Comment: You are not printing anything in your `catch` block in `doInBackground`. Write `e.printStrackTrace()` in the `catch` block and check again.

Comment: You might be getting an exception in your try block. Put a println in your catch block  and check

Comment: This is just a guess but  conexion.connect(); should be closed right? If you let us know which exception is occuring( from logcat) , we may be able to pinpoint the issue

Comment: Probably the "PurchasedFrames" folder doesn't exist. Anyway add `Log.e()` to your exception block and post the error message here.

Comment: check your URL properly.

Comment: Yes, there is no "PurchasedFrames" folder, I thought it will be created automatically. Anyways, @vorrtex could you tell how to create it and save my file to that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my assumption was correct. In my application I used a static method for returning a file path that calls `mkdirs()` in case that such path doesn't exist.

For your code such method would look so:

```
public static File getSaveFilePath(String fileName) {
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "PurchasedFrames");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, fileName);

    return file;
}
```

Then replace the line with output stream:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(getSaveFilePath(fileName));
```

Also replace your exception block with `catch (Exception e) { Log.e("DownloadFileAsync", e.toString()); "}`